# Fourier Transform in special relativistic scenarios

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, fourier-transform

I am currently reading this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/9505032. I want to prove equation 2.11 using 2.3 and 2.1.
The result 2.11 seems quite obvious as $S(x,k)$ looks like a Gaussian in 4D spacetime. I tried to prove the result by simply writing all the terms in the summation in the exponent of $S(x,k)$. I am getting lots of extra terms. And it is becoming very hectic to do all the 4 integrations one by one. I want to know if there exist any shortcut techniques (any theorems, identities,etc.) that can be used to prove the result.

I am stuck in performing this integration

$$\int {d^4}x e^{{-\frac{1}{2}}{x^\mu x^\nu}{B_{\mu\nu}}} e^{iqx}$$

I would appreciate if someone actually does the calculation and post it here.

Comment: You ideally need to show the equations here using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Questions need to be reasonably self-contained and not rely on links.